# No go.exe in JetBrains GoLand. Program won't run. No idea what the problem is

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am working on a program in JetBrains GoLand on my Windows 11 laptop when all of a sudden AVG panics.

When I ignore it, I can't run my program. I get this mystery error that I have never seen before.

```
GOROOT=C:\Users\progn\go\go1.20.4 #gosetup

GOPATH=C:\Users\progn\go #gosetup

Cannot run program "go.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\progn\go\src\at3"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Compilation finished with exit code 126
```

My progress has halted. Can anyone help me with this stuff, please?

Comment: "AVG panics" I'm assuming this is AVG antivirus? Please provide details (what exactly is displayed) and confirm if go works when run from the command prompt (i.e. `go build`). It's likely that AVG is detecting something it considers suspicious and preventing go from running (this may be a false alarm but I cant really say). Maybe try go 1.20.6.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.

I went into the quarantine in AVG and restored the a.out.exe file with a security exception.

I'd like to thank LazyOne for editing my message. I checked his profile and see he's done a ton of work here. I guess he's named LazyOne for the same reason they call thin guys "fats"...